# Prevent sink receiveValue closure from being called immediately

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Consider the following code (you can c&p it directly into a playground):

```
class Foo: ObservableObject {
    @Published var bar = "bar"
}

let foo = Foo()
let someSubscriber = foo.$bar
    .sink { value in
        print("value is \(value)")
    }
```

Although Foo has just been initialised once and it's member `bar` never changed, the sink executes it's `receiveValue` closure immediately. Is there any way to prevent this initial call from happening, e.g. is there an operator I might have overlooked?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `dropFirst` operator. With no argument, it drops just the first output from upstream.

```
let someSubscriber = foo.$bar
    .dropFirst()
    .sink { value in
        print("value is \(value)")
    }
```

---

To address issues raised in the comments:

Each implementation of `Publisher` can decide what to do with each new subscriber. It is a policy decision, not generally a design deficiency. Different `Publisher`s make different decisions. Here are some examples:

- `PassthroughSubject` doesn't immediately publish anything.
- `CurrentValueSubject` immediately publishes its current value.
- `NSObject.KeyValueObservingPublisher` immediately publishes the current value of the observed property if and only if it is created with the `.initial` option.
- `Published.Publisher` (which is the type you get for an `@Published` property) publishes the current value of the property immediately.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Combine, but isn't there a way to make a `@Published`  value with no initial value?

Comment: @Alexander I thing your looking for this here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/publisher

Comment: A `@Published` property always publishes the current value immediately to each new subscriber. You can't stop that from happening. That is why I suggested using `dropFirst`.

Comment: @robmayoff Interesting. In the "regular swift world", we have IUOs for expressing "no sensible default exists until runtime". Is this the closest expression of that in the Combine world?

Comment: But a sensible default does exist, because the property is guaranteed to have a value by the time you can subscribe to its publisher.